# How do I format the TFS work item AssignedTo field with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I'm using TFS 2012 Power Tools and PowerShell to display work items containing change sets which modified source files below a given directory within the last 120 days. With lots of good help from StackOverflow I find the work items and display them like this:

```
PS> $items = Get-TfsItemHistory $/Somewhere -R -All -Version "D$((Get-Date).AddDays(-120).ToString('d'))~" | select ChangesetId -ExpandProperty WorkItems | Sort-Object -Unique Id
PS> $items | format-table
```

This comes out looking fairly good, for example, here's the start of an output:

```
Id    State    AssignedTo    AreaPath            Title
--    -----    ----------    --------            -----
32604 Closed   Harald Han... Client\Domain\Nav   Change to new address space
```

However, if I try to show just a subset of the fields, I can't get the AssignedTo field to display. This is OK:

```
PS> $items | format-table AreaPath, State

AreaPath                  State
--------                  -----
KCS-Client\Domain\Nav     Closed
```

But this is not:

```
PS > $items | format-table AssignedTo, State

AssignedTo                State
----------                -----
                          Closed
```

I must have missed something trivial, but (as a relative newbie to both PowerShell and the TFS PowerTools) I don't see what it is. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property '`AssignedTo`' is a `scriptproperty` evaluated at run time from the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.format.ps1xml` powershell custom format file.

The value is taken from:

```
 $_.Fields[[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.CoreField]::AssignedTo].Value
```

then I think (I can't test it because I don't have a TF Server source ) you need to do:

```
$items | format-table @{n="AssignedTo";e={$_.Fields[[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.CoreField]::AssignedTo].Value}} , State
```

Comment: Just tried it, this works a treat! But how on earth would I have found this on my own? Is there any good documentation about the object model with examples of how to use it?

Comment: A good starting point for powershell custom format file is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878272(v=vs.85).aspx About the object model if you mean tfs objects I can't help.. but you can start to inspect any object piping it to get-member as` $myobject | get-member -force` and look at any membertype and definition. Hope this help